# php post method not working request and get method cannot do anything

Tags: php, html

```
<form name='form-login' action="<?php header("location: /vardhman/administrator/check.php");?>"  method="post">
    <span class="fontawesome-user"></span>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">

    <span class="fontawesome-lock"></span>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">

    <input type="submit" value="Login"></form>
```

this form and

this is the check.php

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="mlm"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="administrator"; // Table name 


// Connect to server and select databse.
$conn= mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 

mysqli_select_db($conn,"$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
if(isset($_POST['username'])) { 
    // check if the username has been set

$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
}
else{
echo "nothing is passed";   
}
```

IT just display nothing is passed.
I don't know what is the problem. 
Please, help me I cannot pass the value. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `</form>` closing tag is missing. Also follow "apokryfos" comment.

Comment: `<?php header("location: /vardhman/administrator/check.php");?>` ? this is really wrong. You only need `/vardhman/administrator/check.php` no php no echo no anything.

Comment: There must be a MILLION tutorials out there on the web that cover this simple process. Could I suggest you google up a couple of these ___and read them___

Comment: is that two files are in same folder..if its yes means,why you are using header location?

Comment: no form tag is closed perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your code. You should not use header() in the action attribute, just write path as plain text

Correct code:

```
<form name='form-login' action="/vardhman/administrator/check.php"  method="post">
```

**Found another bug:**

You should not wrap your variables inside quotes.

```
// Connect to server and select databse.
$conn= mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 

mysqli_select_db($conn,"$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

Correct code:

```
// Connect to server and select databse.
$conn= mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 

mysqli_select_db($conn, $db_name)or die("cannot select DB");
```

Comment: can you tell me the location of your files?

Comment: location of the file is same. thanks for extra help.

Comment: if the files are in same place then you can simply use action="check.php"

Comment: yeah! I try that but why answer is going in else loop I cannot understand.

Comment: try var_dumb($_POST['username']); before if(isset($_POST['username'])) and tell me what you get.

Comment: oops! sorry. it is var_dump($_POST['username']);

Comment: Undefined index: and also var_dump showing null means value is not passing.

Comment: Ok. It means you are not receiving $_POST['username'] variable.